# Javascript: Collision Detection help (HTML5 Canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

I am trying to throw together a platformer in HTML5 using the new canvas feature. I was implementing a somewhat simple way to do collision with rectangles, and it worked until I added multiple rectangles. Basically I have a function which adds a new object to an array with all the atributes needed to draw the rectangle. The collision detection loops through the array and checks and corrects collisions. When I added another rectangle on top, it freaks out when you are standing on the bottom one, and then you jump and hit the bottom of the top one.

Here is the [main javascript file](http://www.keirp.com/canvas/engine.js), and here is a [demo](http://www.keirp.com/canvas) that I threw up on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Your collision detection code is OK, the only problem is that it is not working the way you want. A simple fix could be only check the collision with platforms when the player is falling down. (Line 188)

`if ((player.yvel > 0) && (player.y + player.height > rect[i].y) && (player.y < rect[i].y + rect[i].height))`